# Pros and Cons of distributing PDB files in a release build of a Desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, build, release

I want to get more detailed exceptions in automated crash reports in my desktop applications.

I am thinking about including PDB files in my release builds, but i have not found good recommendations online.

I have seen a lot of people suggesting to generate crash dumps instead, but sometimes i am not able to generate or retrieve/get the additional files, and all i have is the initial crash report containing the stack trace.

What are the dangers of releasing PDB's in the release builds of a desktop application distributed to thousands of users?

Comment: The danger is that your user will debug your code for you, telling you what is wrong with it.  If you want file+line info then you must include the pdbs.  Just keep in mind that it won't be reliable, the code is optimized so methods will be missing because they got inlined and the line number might be off because the code was moved.

Answer (score 1):

Pros: Can't think of any.

Cons: Shipping the PDBs will result in your application using significantly more storage (3x approx) which your users may not appreciate.

How is a shipping the PDB strategy better than diagnosing the crash report on your machine where you have the source and PDBs that match the application that crashed on the user's machine?

Comment: I am not claiming anything is better or worse.. i am just asking about pros and cons :)

Comment: I am aware of the size increase, and that is not a problem in my scenario.

Comment: I assume you have some pros in mind if you're considering the option. I can't think of any but maybe you have a special environment?

Comment: I just need a detailed stacktrace with line numbers, including additional information in the crash report i get from users. I am just looking at ways to retrieve that. Of course that the diagnosis of the problem will be done on my machine when i have all needed information. It is better to have as much detail as possible (stacktrace, process info, crash dump), than just some basic info (e.g. exception type and message).

Comment: The desktop applications i am shipping to the users are relatively small in size.. so a 3x size increase is not a big deal.